# 0-vectors in a vector field

Tags: tikz-arrows

I'm trying to plot a vector field with 5 by 5 arrows (25 in total). It looks good, expect for the fact that it arbitrarily chooses "up" as the direction of the 0-vector. How can I tell it to not display 0-length arrows at all?

My code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\tikzset{>=stealth} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[->, thick] (-3,0)--(3,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->, thick] (0,-3)--(0,3) node[above] {$y$};

\def\factor{0.15}
\foreach \x in {-2.5,-2,...,2.5} {
    \foreach \y in {-2.5,-2,...,2.5}{
            \draw[->] (\x,\y)--++(\factor*\y,-\factor*\x);
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result (note the arrow tip at the origin):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility with `\ifthenelse`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usepackage{ifthen}
\tikzset{>=stealth} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[->, thick] (-3,0)--(3,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->, thick] (0,-3)--(0,3) node[above] {$y$};

\def\factor{0.15}
\foreach \x in {-2.5,-2,...,2.5} {
    \foreach \y [evaluate=\y as \r using int(ceil(abs(\x)+abs(\y)))] in {-2.5,-2,...,2.5}{
            \ifthenelse{\r=0}{}{\draw[->] (\x,\y)--++(\factor*\y,-\factor*\x);}
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a great answer because of its generality: it doesn't directly check if x=y=0, it checks if the vector itself is 0.

Answer (score 3):

Throw in a couple `\ifx` checks for zero.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\tikzset{>=stealth} 
\newcommand*\zero{0}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[->, thick] (-3,0)--(3,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->, thick] (0,-3)--(0,3) node[above] {$y$};

\def\factor{0.15}
\foreach \x in {-2.5,-2,...,2.5} {
    \foreach \y in {-2.5,-2,...,2.5}{
     \def\tmp{\draw[->] (\x,\y)--++(\factor*\y,-\factor*\x)}
     \ifx\zero\x\ifx\zero\y\else\tmp\fi\else\tmp\fi;
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I'm not familiar with this syntax (what is \fi?), can you please direct me to a (preferably simple) explanation? Also, I notice the use of a command \zero; is it generalizable to other conditional statements? E.g. x is not 2, x is greater than 1 etc.

Comment: @35T41 TeX provides basic conditonals (see TeXbook by Knuth, p.209), the one I use here is `\ifx` which tests two unexpanded tokens for identicality.  The form of all if-conditions are `\ifx<condition><true code>\else<false code>\fi`  So `fi`, being `if` backwards, is what closes out the if condition.

Comment: @35T41 Thus, in my code, I compare the identicality of `\zero` and `\x` and also `\zero` and `\y`.  If both conditions are true, I do nothing, otherwise, I execute `\tmp`, which is the `\draw` statement.

Answer (score 3):

It's best to avoid decimal numbers in `\foreach`, because of rounding problems. You can test whether both `\x` and `\y` are zero:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{>=stealth} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[->, thick] (-3,0)--(3,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->, thick] (0,-3)--(0,3) node[above] {$y$};

\def\factor{0.15}
\foreach \x in {-5,-4,...,5} {
  \foreach \y in {-5,-4,...,5}{
    \pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(and(\x==0,\y==0),1,0)}
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=0
      \draw[->] (\x/2,\y/2)--++(\factor*\y/2,-\factor*\x/2);
    \fi
  }
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]