# How to draw this vector field?

Tags: graphics

I dont have a lot of knowledge in LaTex and I want to draw a vector field like this,  just a simple graph. The examples I have seen in other questions are a little more elaborate, I am looking for something simpler. Thank you for any answer.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/614618/0-vectors-in-a-vector-field

Comment: If the above link does not provide an answer to your question, please consider providing a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows what you tried so far and where you got stuck exactly. I think, even if the above link does not exactly provide a solution to your probem, it should be able to serve as a starting point. It is much easier to help you, if you provide some code to start with.